# Trying to create a button which removes the task from the list, but the filter method won't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm able to push values but not sure where i'm going wrong with the filtering. Can someone guide me if i'm using the filter method wrong or is it something else?

```
import { useState } from 'react';

const App = () => {
const [task,setTask] = useState('');
const [list,setList] = useState([]);

const submitHandler = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const newTask = { id: new Date().getTime().toString(), title: task };
      setList([...list, newTask]);
      setTask('');
}

const clearList = () => {
  setList([]);
}

const removeItem = (id) => {
    const filteredList = list.filter(item => item.id !== id);
    setList(filteredList);
}

  return <div>
          <h2>To do list!</h2>
          <form onSubmit={submitHandler}> Enter Task! 
          <input type='text'
            onChange = {(event) => {setTask(event.target.value)}}>
          </input>
          </form>
          <div>
          {list.map((obj) => (
          <h4 key={obj.id}>{obj.title}<button onClick={removeItem}>X</button></h4>))}
          <button onClick={clearList}>Clear All</button>
          </div>
          </div>
}

export default App
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment you're calling `removeItem` by using `onClick={removeItem}`, which will pass an event object to your  `removeItem` function, and not an *id* like your function is expecting to receive.  You'll want to pass your `removeItem` method the *id* of the object you want to remove when you click, which can be done by passing `obj.id` into it:

```html
...
<button onClick={() => removeItem(obj.id)}>X</button>
...
```